# Importing Python libraries in Openshift cron jobs

Tags: python, cron, openshift

I have a script in .openshift/cron/daily that looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'])
import EmilyBlogModel
EmilyBlogModel.Poll()
```

EmilyBlogModel.py is in $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR

However, when the cron job runs, I get an ImportError

```
No module named EmilyBlogModel
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: It has to be something to do with directory paths. I use the bash script and execute my python script directly. Ex. Python myscript.py. You might have to provide full path to your script. I can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing the system path before the import statement? OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR might be pointing to the wrong path.